# Пунктуация в предложении со вставкой

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сложное-предложение, вставная-конструкция

*Время обеда еще не наступило, а потому в «Мясном рынке» было тихо — два старика неторопливо попивали пиво в разных концах бара, усердно игнорируя друг друга — не иначе как между ними пробежала черная кошка, двое молодых безработных гоняли шары.*
[И. Рэнкин. Плоть и кровь](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=34731&p=72) (перевод с английского Г. Крылова)

Я думаю, что часть предложения "не иначе как между ними пробежала черная кошка" является вставной конструкцией. Но тогда, как мне кажется, пунктуация должна быть другой.
Как бы вы расставили знаки в этом предложении?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант редактирования:

Время обеда еще не наступило, **и поэтому** в «Мясном рынке» было тихо: два старика неторопливо попивали пиво в разных концах бара, усердно игнорируя друг друга, **— не иначе как между ними пробежала черная кошка, —** двое молодых безработных гоняли шары.

Пояснение

Предложение имеет сложную грамматику, поэтому вставку лучше **выделить запятыми и тире** (первая запятая поставлена для симметрии).

**Двоеточие** лучше подходит для обозначения **пояснительного характера** второй части сложного предложения, также оно используется в тех случаях, когда в предложении уже есть тире.

Comment: А можно ли оставить пунктуацию — как есть? Считается ли это ошибкой?

Comment: Думаю, что нет.  Вставка не обозначена двумя тире, а это именно вставка, а два поставленных тире  можно отнести к вставной конструкции, в то время как первое тире должно обозначать  бессоюзную связь. Знаки препинания затемняют структуру предложения, а не поясняют ее.

Comment: @Sharon Я не могу понять второе тире в Вашей редакции. Думаю, что без него лучше. Там же заканчивается смысловой фрагмент о стариках, а к безработным та кошка не имеет отношения. Вы уверены?

Comment: Я думаю, что здесь такая структура (без вставки): "В «Мясном рынке» было тихо: два старика неторопливо попивали пиво в разных концах бара, двое молодых безработных гоняли шары". А вставка всегда обособляется двумя тире, выбирается только количество запятых.

Answer (score 2):

Вы, как всегда, наблюдательны и хорошо чувствуете грамматику предложения. Я бы предложила такую пунктуацию:

***Время обеда еще не наступило, а потому в «Мясном рынке» было тихо: два старика неторопливо попивали пиво в разных концах бара, усердно игнорируя друг друга (не иначе как между ними пробежала черная кошка), двое молодых безработных гоняли шары.***

Двоеточие в БСП, потому что вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой (тихо, а именно: старики пьют пиво, да безработные гоняют шары).

Скобки, потому что вставная конструкция поясняет деепричастие **игнорируя**. Мы помним, что скобками мы выделяем:

1) вставные конструкции, дополняющие или поясняющие содержание основного предложения:

*Наконец он велел запрячь себе беговые дрожки, оделся потеплее (это было уже в конце сентября) и, сам правя, выехал со двора* (П.); *Молодой воробей выпал из гнезда (ветер сильно качал берёзы аллеи) и сидел неподвижно* (Т.);

2) вставные конструкции, представляющие собой попутные авторские замечания:

*Поверьте (совесть в том порукой), супружество нам будет мукой* (П.);

3) вставные конструкции, поясняющие отдельные слова в основном предложении:

*Нет, вы (или ты) этого не должны знать!* (Л.); *А где стара? (Так он обыкновенно называл жену свою.)* (Г.);

4) вставные конструкции, синтаксически связанные с основным предложением, но выключенные из него и носящие присоединительный характер:

*Враги его, друзья его (что, может быть, одно и то же) его честили так и сяк* (П.);

5) вставные вопросительные и восклицательные конструкции и отдельные слова, выражающие эмоции автора или его отношение к высказанным словам, к цитатам.

При помощи тире выделяются вставные конструкции, дополняющие или поясняющие основное предложение, выражающие чувства автора и т. д. (часто в произведениях художественной литературы).

У нас поясняется не всё предложение, а только деепричастие (поясняется, почему они игнорируют друг друга), поэтому здесь уместны скобки.

Тире вместо двоеточия тоже возможно, ведь сейчас причинно-следственные связи обозначаются тире или двоеточием по выбору автора, оттенок причины и следствия здесь есть: тихо, потому что только старики да бильярдисты были в рынке.

Но вот два тире в том виде, как у автора перевода, нежелательны.

*Время обеда еще не наступило, а потому в «Мясном рынке» было тихо — два старика неторопливо попивали пиво в разных концах бара, усердно игнорируя друг друга, — не иначе как между ними пробежала черная кошка, двое молодых безработных гоняли шары.*

Объяснить их можно. Автор, видимо, вторым тире тоже хотел подчеркнуть следственные связи или указать на пояснение (игнорируя — это между ними пробежала чёрная кошка), но между тире оказалась фраза  **два старика неторопливо попивали пиво в разных концах бара, усердно игнорируя друг друга**, а это не вставка, это вторая часть БСП, раскрывающая содержание первой, она не обособлена от основного предложения. Смысл предложения искажён, это ошибка.

Comment: _Вы, как всегда, наблюдательны и хорошо чувствуете грамматику предложения._ Признательна за оценку. И ответ (я позволила себе его подправить — надеюсь, что Вы не против).

Comment: Нет, не против, спасибо.